# QXmlStreamReader raises UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, pyqt, qtxml, qxmlstreamreader

A piece of code that works with Python 2 does not work with Python 3 on my system.

```
f = open("plotwidget.svg")
svgData = f.read()
xml_stream = QtCore.QXmlStreamReader(svgData)
```

This raises the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 12688: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The character is indeed not an ASCII character, but I don't understand why `QXmlStreamReader` expects to find a `latin-1` encoding when the file seems to be a proper UTF-8 file with the encoding specified in the header.

The SVG file was generated with `matplotlib` (`figure.savefig(...)`).

Comment: whats is your pyqt version?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution, it expected bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because the constructor requires bytes and not strings, the solution is to use `encode()`.

```
xml_stream = QtCore.QXmlStreamReader(svgData.encode())
```